# Renaming files in a folder using a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need a.bat script to rename all files in a folder always respecting a numerical order.
I have this code, but I don't like the result. How to obtain numerical sorting instead of a lexicographical sorting?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "pasta=E:\Google Drive\_Projetos em andamento\Ano 2023\Album\Testando"
set "contador=1"

cd /d "%pasta%"

REM Ensure files are sorted numerically and rename them
for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /b /on *.jpg') do (
    set "novo_nome=00!contador!.jpg"
    ren "%%F" "!novo_nome!"
    set /a "contador+=1"
)

endlocal
```

original names
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghhsy.png)

Names renamed out of numerical order
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRa1M.png)
Note that the files are out of order:
1,10,11,12,13,114,15,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 (Correct form)

Folder with files to test
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4e09d2c0851ed566f37c4cc63916c58720230903163115/9a7d0c

Comment: Do the original filenames akways follow the pattern String(number),jpg?

Comment: @Magoo, The original files will always follow the numerical order pattern, I just need to add a new name respecting its original order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for each file get the number in parentheses, add 1000 and take the last three digits of that:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in ("IMG (*).jpg") do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=()" %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
    set /a number=1000+%%B
    ECHO ren "%%A" "!number:~-3!%%~xA"
  )
)
```

Remove the `ECHO` if the output satisfies you to actually enable the `ren` command.

Comment: Hi Stephan, here is your code modified with the help of GPT chat to meet my need.
https://pastebin.com/raw/YUXDN9xN
This script works correctly if the ordering digits
using parentheses as delimiters, how do I modify the code to remove any character and not just parentheses, thus being able to rename any file name, of course always respecting its numerical order.